# Why is "-the Maxim-" in the title?

Tags: parasyte

I suspect there may be a *Your Lie in April* title spoiler situation here, or quite possibly I'm just dense. I'm on episode 10 of *Parasyte -the Maxim-* and I have been wondering the whole time what the title means.  At a guess, it could involve how episode 1 starts and ends.

- **start:** Someone on Earth had a sudden thought.
- **end:** Someone on Earth had a sudden thought. "Life must be protected."

(The end quote appears at time mark 20:40.) The Google dictionary defines **maxim** as "a short, pithy statement expressing a general truth or rule of conduct".  So is that **the** maxim, *Life must be protected.*? If so, there will probably be a further reveal late in the series. Or am I way off base?

If the actual answer is a spoiler, please put it in a spoiler block. I'll hold off reading that part until finishing the series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are right on the mark that the maxim *is* "Life must be protected."

From what I remember, the theme is pretty consistent throughout the entire series, but the overarching idea tied to **the** maxim is that all life is valuable, regardless of species.

It's a bit philosophical for an anime about aliens that hijack human bodies and blend in so they can eat other humans while no one is looking, but bear with me.

---

One way that the series plays into this maxim is by seemingly asking "Who is *really* a monster?", as in "Who really deserves to live/die?"

> After the initial brutality of the Parasites, some of them start to realize that the best way to continue their existence is to co-exist with the humans. However, most humans oppose this idea completely, due to first impressions and not-so-peaceful Parasites. This idea comes to a climax in episode 21 where the presumed Parasite mayoral candidate Hirokawa condemns humans for not being able to live alongside Parasites and is shot to death. Only after this is it revealed that Hirokawa was fully human the entire time.

Another scene that depicts Parasites as not complete monsters is in Episode 18,

> when Reiko sacrifices herself to save her son.

---

The other way that this maxim is used throughout the series is the idea of *survival*.

That is, the Parasites simply seek to survive, and

> as mentioned above, seek to cooperate with humans, though they are rejected entirely and effectively forced into hiding, lest they be hunted, as seen in Episodes 19-20.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and especially the spoiler blocks.  I haven't peeked!  I think there may have been a hint in episode 10 (?) too.  It involved a conversation between Reiko and some boss parasite guy.  I won't say what it was because I don't think we can use spoiler blocks in comments.

Comment: @RichF yeah, comments don't allow a lot of the markup that you can use in answers, so good call there. It's been a while since I've watched Parasyte, honestly. I had to re-read up on a bunch of the plot to write this answer, but life is a very prevalent theme throughout the show. Hopefully, once you're finished with the show, you can look back at this answer and agree with what I've said! :-)

Comment: Just finished the series; it is really good.  I have also read your spoilers now, allowing me to mark this answer as the one I *accept*.  Of course right now it is the only answer, but it is a good one!

Answer (score 2):

I remember in the series there was a bit where Migi shows his new dividing ability that he has learned to use. He says that because each new entity will contain a fraction of the thinking power of the original, he gives a simple maxim to each 'come together as one'. Not sure if its the right answer tho.

I like the 'life must be protected' idea Vemonus posted, that is a good answer.